# git add -A and git add . command failing

Tags: git, heroku

This is the error while using the git add command.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>git add . 
error: open("AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Cache/data_0"): Permission denied error: unable to index file AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Cache/ data_0 fatal: adding files failed
```

I guess it's a problem of locating the path of the files to add. I want to add to the repo and push it to my heroku server.
I've tried git add -A as well.
Will the ... command help?

I'm new to web development.
Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using poshgit or GitHub for Windows? What version are you using?

Comment: which repo have you to add to? Where is the repo is located locally?

Comment: I'm using git bash 1.8.1.2

Comment: It is c:\users\administrator\.git. This is Windows incase i have'nt mentioned

Comment: As in http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5ccb7bad-eae1-49ce-9ae1-9378d89d2dbb/windows-7-sp1-2008-r2-sp1-roaming-event-1509?forum=winservergen, are you using an anti-virus software which would block access to that folder?